# Error converting C# code to VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following C# code

```
charValue = text[charIndex++];
```

Via the C# to VB.NET converter at [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com), it has given me this code:

```
charValue = text (
    System.Math.Max(
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(charIndex),charIndex - 1))
```

However, when I copy the converted code in, I am getting an error.

Comment: very unclear. You should say what is the `exception` or the compilation error.

Comment: So.......what's the error?

Comment: Try alternative converters until you find one that gives the answer provided by Slai.

Answer (score 2):

```
charValue = text[charIndex++];
```

in C# is shortcut for

```
charValue = text[charIndex]; 
charIndex += 1;
```

and in VB.Net:

```
charValue = text(charIndex)
charIndex += 1
```

Comment: @Zaggler "[The result of the operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w)"

Comment: charvalue and charindex is integer im having problem again :(

Comment: Both wrong, using the ++ after the operand is the before value before it was incremented so it should be `charValue = text(charIndex - 1)`. If it was `++char..` it would be `textValue = (charIndex + 1)`

Comment: @Zaggler, you are wrong... both times.  Apart from anything else, the `++` operator in C#, whether pre- or post-, will change the value of the variable it's applied to but NONE of the VB code you provided would change the value of `charIndex`, therefore it's not equivalent.

Comment: I know it won't change charIndex didn't say it would. It would have to be `charValue = text(charIndex - 1) charIndex +=1 ` The ++ after is the before increment which is why the -1, it's not wrong in what I'm saying... hence also why the converter is doing it the way it was. The answer provided is wrong because it's saying the next value first and that's not correct.